# How to know what URL the browser was before it got redirected to my page

Tags: javascript, url, dom, location, location-href

So if `example123.com` have a:

```
window.location = "mysite.com";
```

OR user clicked

```
<a href="mysite.com">go to my site</a>
```

OR ANY OTHER METHOD OF REDIRECTING

**IF I'M ON** `mysite.com` How will I know that it came from `example123.com`?

Comment: Checke the [referer request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) on your server for incoming requests

Comment: I'm sorry, how do you do that if you're in react?

Comment: Please **carefully** check the tags you are using: [tag:location] seems **massively** unsuitable and [tag:dom] doesn't fit either.

Comment: coz I'm doing it on the DOM and not the server? :(

Comment: The browser is not the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.referrer` seems to do the job for me.

Comment: explain the downvote pls? is this wrong?